# gem sources fails with a ETIMEDOUT

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemcutter

gem sources -a http://gemcutter.org 
Error fetching http://gemcutter.org:
       Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected
party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established conn
ction failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (h
tp://gemcutter.org/specs.4.8.gz)

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply put sources into config file in your home directory.

`cat ~/.gemrc`

```
---
:sources: 
- http://rubygems.org
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar message when I tried to install an app. And the problem was that at work my pc was behind a proxy. so, I solved by doing this:

```
gem install whatever --http-proxy=http://user:pass@proxy:port
```

http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/799-ruby-gem-install-problems-on-windows-xp